# How to select rows corresponding to a randomly selected column value in SQL

Tags: sql, random, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, sql-order-by

My query returns a result like shown in the table. I would like to randomly pick an ID from the `ID` column and get all the rows having that `ID`. How can I do that in SnowFlake or SQL:

| ID | Postalcode | Value | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1e3d | NK25F4 | 3214 | ... |
| 1e3d | NK25F4 | 3258 | ... |
| 1e3d | NK25F4 | 3354 | ... |
| 1f74 | NG2LK8 | 5524 |  |
| 1f74 | NG2LK8 | 5548 |  |
| 3e9a | N6B7H4 | 3694 |  |
| 3e9a | N6B7H4 | 3325 |  |
| 38e4 | N6C7H2 | 3654 | ... |

Answer (score 3):

There is a Snowflake function to return a fix number of "random" rows [SAMPLE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/sample.html), so using that will reduce the need to read all rows.

```
SELECT t.* 
FROM your_table as t
JOIN (SELECT ID FROM your_table SAMPLE (1 ROWS)) as r
    ON t.id = r.id
```

thus using your data above:

```
with your_table(id, postalcode, value) as (
    select * from values 
        ('1e3d', 'NK25F4', 3214),   
        ('1e3d', 'NK25F4', 3258),   
        ('1e3d', 'NK25F4', 3354),
        ('1f74', 'NG2LK8', 5524),   
        ('1f74', 'NG2LK8', 5548),   
        ('3e9a', 'N6B7H4', 3694),   
        ('3e9a', 'N6B7H4', 3325),   
        ('38e4', 'N6C7H2', 3654)
)
```

I get (random set) but one looks like:

| ID | POSTALCODE | VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1f74 | NG2LK8 | 5,524 |
| 1f74 | NG2LK8 | 5,548 |

You could also use a NATURAL JOIN like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM your_table
NATURAL JOIN (SELECT ID FROM your_table SAMPLE (1 ROWS))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could put your existing query in a common table expression, then pick a random ID from it, and use it to filter the dataset:

```
with
    dat as ( ... your query ...),
    tid as (select id from dat order by random() fetch first 1 row)
select d.*
from dat d
inner join tid t on t.id = d.id
```

The second CTE, `tid` picks the random id; it does that by randomly ordering the dataset, then getting the id of the top row.

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table_NAME 
WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM Table_Name ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1);
```

Should work. Though it's not particularly efficient and in many application scenarios it would arguably be more reasonable overall to compute the random ID in your application (e.g. keeping the set of all ids cached, periodically pulling it separately if need be etc).

(Note: The query assumes MYSQL, other variants may have slightly different keywords/structure, e.g. for the random function).

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
WITH DATA AS (
select '1e3d' id,'NK25F4' postalcode,3214 some_value union all   
select '1e3d' id,'NK25F4' postalcode,3258 some_value union all 
select '1e3d' id,'NK25F4' postalcode,3354 some_value union all   
select '1f74' id,'NG2LK8' postalcode,5524 some_value union all  
select '1f74' id,'NG2LK8' postalcode,5548 some_value union all  
select '3e9a' id,'N6B7H4' postalcode,3694 some_value union all  
select '3e9a' id,'N6B7H4' postalcode,3325 some_value union all  
select '38e4' id,'N6C7H2' postalcode,3654 some_value )
SELECT * FROM DATA ,LATERAL (SELECT ID FROM DATA SAMPLE(2 ROWS)) I WHERE I.ID = DATA.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also play with the `window frame` a little and let `qualify` do the work

```
select *
from your_table
qualify id=first_value(id) over (order by random() rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following)
```

Snowflake deviates from ANSI standard on the default window frames for rank-related functions (`first_value`, `last_value`, `nth_value`), so that makes the above equivalent to :

```
select *
from your_table
qualify id=first_value(id) over (order by random())
```